# PHP - MVC within MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm learning about MVC frameworks, and I am about to start building a website that will eventually store all of my work. I plan to build a simple blog system using a MVC framework. But then I also want to host my other work within that MVC. For instance, if I have just created a simple todo list app that is also built with an MVC framework, I want to be host that on my portfolio too.

For instance, `myportfolio.com` will be the main app. `myportfolio.com/otherapp` will be a piece of work that I would like to host on my portfolio.

Can anybody provide any suggestions as to how this might be achieved, without having to port all models, views and controllers to a single main app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make an exception on how the URL is handled. `myportfolio.com/`, `myportfolio.com/foo`, `myportfolio.com/bar` etc. are all handled by your MVC blogging system, only `myportfolio.com/otherapp` is handled by your otherapp. This can simply be achieved through RewriteRules in an .htaccess file, but how exactly depends on how exactly your framework works.

Comment: Why not just incorporate them all into the same underlying system?

Comment: @Jared If that's possible, sure, but it seems that's exactly what the OP doesn't want to do.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just trying to get my head around the .htaccess stuff. I'm following this tutorial to create my own MVC: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw28-krO7ZM

Comment: That's true (the last sentence didn't really register). As an aside, if it's not a truly complex setup, *not* incorporating them could be less desirable in the long term than just biting the bullet now.